# Writing regex pattern with multiple conditions

Tags: java, regex

I want to find urls in a html content String in Java. This urls should have some conditions.

As an Example consider below String.

```
"background-image: url("https://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz_gif/uMa5Y2rQ8PkXuk9veIibUjBk1iaxlKqoAeBKejmFicic0C3lZuG58rYIPAHzsR6icicecc58OacuXeZ9CUicvG1d5ib3v/0?wx_fmt=gif") style="display: flex;" "
```

I want to extract  `https://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz_gif/uMa5Y2rQ8PkXuk9veIibUjBk1iaxlKqoAeBKejmFicic0C3lZuG58rYIPAHzsR6icicecc58OacuXeZ9CUicvG1d5ib3v/0?wx_fmt=gif`

I need to write a regex pattern which can be start from both https and http, then `://mmbiz.qpic.cn/` should present, then can be any string.

Comment: "can be any string" needs to be clarified. Urls are always contained between quotes?

Comment: yes starting and ending quotes always there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the starting quote, then a non-greedy search till the next quote, this way:

```
(?<=\")(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?mmbiz\.qpic\.cn[^\"]+
```

Check the [**demo and explaination**](https://regex101.com/r/8gFaWy/1)

#### Version 2

If you also want to be able to track single quotes use this:

```
(?<=[\"\'])(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?mmbiz\.qpic\.cn[^\"\']+
```

[**Demo and explaination**](https://regex101.com/r/8gFaWy/2)

Comment: I need to track single quote as well not only the double quote. is it possible.

I tried,
(?<=\" | ?<=\')(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?mmbiz\.qpic\.cn[^\" | \']+

Answer (score 0):

Please try following regex hope it works for you:

`[^\"]*http[s]*://mmbiz.qpic.cn(.*?)[^\"]*`